# Are we going to get a Protected Date field in Question responses?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, protected-questions

Now that questions can be marked protected, will this info be available via the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

`protected_date` has been added as an optionally returned field.

[Example (SuperUser)](http://api.superuser.com/0.8/questions/95685)